# learning python stuck on project

Tags: python

im self learning programming (python) i gave myself a project to programme the Beaufort scale. ive done this, see below, but every time i input wind speed i am given all possible answers, not the answer i programmed it to give me. can anyone enlighten me on the error of my ways please.

```
wind_speed = (input("What is the wind speed? "))

if wind_speed <= "3":
print("light airs drifting conditions")
if wind_speed > "3" <= '6':
print("Light breeze, sail: full sail and large genoa.")
if wind_speed > "7" <= "10":
print("Gentle breeze, sail: full sail")
if wind_speed > "11" <= "16":
print("Moderate, Sail: reduce headsail size")
if wind_speed > "17" <= '21':
print("Fresh breeze,sail: reef mainsail")
if wind_speed > '22' <= '27':
print("Strong breeze,sail:reef main sail and reduce headsail")
if wind_speed > '28' <= '33':
print("Near gale, sail: deep reefed main sail, small jib")
if wind_speed > '34' <= '40':
print("Gale, sail: deep reefed main, small jib")
if wind_speed > '41' <= '47':
print("Severe gale, sail: trysail and storm jib")
if wind_speed > '48' <= '55':
print("Storm,survival conditions")
else:
print("SKillz")
```

Comment: Briefly: you are comparing strings, not numbers. Also, your comparisons are chaining as "if wind speed is more than some small number and that small number is smaller than a larger number" - you should be doing `low < x <= high`, not `x > low <= high`.

Comment: Hey! Please check this link. It will help you to understand the logical operator and conditional statement.
https://geek-university.com/python/use-logical-operators/

Comment: thank you, i will give it a go